In Kafka Streams KGroupedTable.aggregate, should the adder and subtractor return a new immutable aggregator on every call?
I want to aggregate KTable entries to a Map of Sets (e.g. Map<Set<String>>), so in the aggregate function I need to provide adder and subtractor, which look like this:
(key, value, map) -> {
  map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new HashSet<>()).add(value);
  return map;
},
(key, value, map) -> {
  map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new HashSet<>()).remove(value)
  return map;
}

My question is: Is it OK to return the map as is, or should the aggregator be an immutable object, which force me to deep clone the entire map of sets on every call?

It should be ok to modify the passed in aggregate parameter (ie, your map). There should be no need to deep-copy it.
